# Is there a way to respond to Twilio studio executions programmatically?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I would like to build an end-to-end test of my Twilio Studio Flow, where it receives an incoming call and from there proceeds to expect user input via dial-pad and voice. I've also connected the REST API as an additional trigger to point to the same tree as the voice path. So far I can create a new execution of said flow and have the steps returned, and from there I would like to respond to each additional step with test input (in the form of TwiML) and continue the execution to determine the pass/fail of my tests with expected input.

Comment: Hi, did you succeed in running an end-to-end tests? If so, how did you respond to each step?

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent blog I read that may be of interest to you.

Automating how IVR call flows are tested

https://tech.ovoenergy.com/automating-how-ivr-call-flows-are-tested/

ivr-tester

https://github.com/SketchingDev/ivr-tester

That said, is there a particular issue you encountered with the above approach you are taking? It is not clear what the issue is.